# Can an F1 student apply for CPT (curricular practical training) with a pending I-485 (Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status)?

Tags: usa, non-residents, internship

The F1 student is in the US. I read conflicting answers. E.g., https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-i-apply-for-a-cpt-application-with-pending-aos-2179596.html says yes and no.

Comment: You got two conflicting answers from two attorneys, what makes you think you'll get a better answer here? It's either "yes" or "no" and you have both versions already. Practically speaking it would be meaningless, if you already applied for EAD under one criteria - why apply again under a different and more restrictive one, even if you're eligible?

Comment: @littleadv attorneys aren't always right.

Comment: Clearly, one of those is wrong. But does it matter which? Why?

Comment: @littleadv student wants to intern before getting EAD/green card (can take >1y).

Comment: Students can intern with unrestricted EAD, why ask for a restricted one? Since they already applied for unrestricted one, which is essentially automatic, there's no reason to believe that the restricted one (which actually goes through manual approval) would come faster. There's absolutely no sense in this course of action.

Comment: @littleadv student doesn't have EAD. CPT is way faster to get.

Comment: The question states that they applied for EAD based on their I-485. This is issued automatically, usually within less than 3 months (I got it within less than 1 month at the time). CPT is not at all faster.

Comment: @littleadv took >1y for me. CPT is just a few weeks.

Comment: @littleadv good point, I forgot about that. I got me EAD in around 2 months and 2 weeks. But either way, CPT is still on average faster (~3 weeks) and more predictable than getting EAD. Also, I didn't get my second EAD card before my first EAD expired. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing about immigration intent in the [CPT eligibility](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/practical-training). The second attorney is wrong.

That said, as I explained in the comments - it would make no sense to do this. I-765 filed concurrently with (or based on) pending I-485 is processed automatically. CPT requires manual approvals from the DSO and USCIS to confirm eligibility of the program and the student. If the first one has already been filed, the chances of getting the second one approved sooner are slim at best and even then the time difference would be insignificant.

Comment: CPT requires [approval by the school DSO only](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sevis-help-hub/student-records/fm-student-employment/f-1-curricular-practical-training-cpt). The approval must be entered in SEVIS and printed on the I-20, but no manual approval by the government. Depending on school policy it might be approved very fast.